# Compare current item with previous in f:for loop

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I want to group my appointments by `startDate` (and later by `lawyer.fullName`).
So I want to display the appointment's `startDate` only if the previous appointment's `startDate` is different.
This is what I tried. But I really have no idea how I can get the object from the previous operation.
**Line 3** is where the fail happens right now...

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{appointments}" as="paginatedAppointments">
        <f:for each="{paginatedAppointments}" as="appointment" iteration="i">
            <f:if condition="{appointment.startDate->f:format.date(format:'d.m.Y')} != {0:paginatedAppointments.{i.index-1}.startDate->f:format.date(format:'d.m.Y')}">
                <f:then>
                    <br/>
                    {appointment.startDate->f:format.date(format:'d.m.Y')}<br/>
                    {appointment.startTime->f:format.date(format:'H:i')}<br/>
                    {appointment.lawyer.fullName}<br/><br/>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    {appointment.startTime->f:format.date(format:'H:i')}<br/>
                    {appointment.lawyer.fullName}<br/>
                    <br/><br/>
                </f:else>
            </f:if>
        </f:for>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

Keep in mind if you have an answer: **I would really like to keep using this useful paginate widget** if possible.

--Edit--

I noticed that an answer from another question solved my question perfectly in terms of the grouping for `DateTime` objects so I marked my question as a duplicate. Thanks to Jigal's answer I found it, because I forgot about `f:groupedFor`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `ViewHelper` with some value to compare as an argument that saves the `startDate` in a static variable and returns true/false if it is different from the last one. It is also useful if it has some kind of reset function, so something like that:

```
{vendor:utility.compareLast(reset:1)}

        <f:for each="{paginatedAppointments}" as="appointment" iteration="i">
            <f:if condition="{vendor:utility.compareLast(value:'{appointment.startDate->f:format.date(format:\'d.m.Y\')}')}">
...
```

Comment: As I have never created a ViewHelper before it would take too much time to learn this right now, but I'll look at it later - thanks!

Comment: Creating a ViewHelper is so easy that it is not worth not creating one.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to make one -  thanks for the motivation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `f:groupedFor` viewhelper and you can group the items by startDate. In the inner loop you can check the iterator if it's the first and display the startDate in that case. See [Fluid Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/GroupedFor.html)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for well DateTimeObjects apparently, not in my case - it works well for grouping by lawyers though!

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't designed to work with DateTimeObjects. Will have a look in the core code to see what prevents it from working.